# How to compare local branch with remote branch in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, remote-branch

Can someone show me how to compare a local branch with remote branch to see the all the differences or new changesets added?

I only want to see what's new like `hg incoming` or `hg outgoing`. I don't want to compare individual files.

It would be something like this `hg incoming --branches Branch:Branch` so the first one is the local branch and second is the remote branch, something like that.

Comment: I think it is `hg incoming --branch default`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so I will give the answer of my own question:

We can apparently use `-b` (or `--branch` in the exact way) flag with commands like `hg incoming` and `hg outgoing`. So when I want to compare a specific branch I need to do the followings

1. Compare local branch1 with remote branch1: `hg outgoing -b branch1`
2. Compare remote branch1 with local branch1: `hg incoming -b branch1`

This helps.